# Pass json objects into another function to call in a for loop

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, xmlhttprequest, jsonparser

I have a function that gets a list of json objects through XmlHTTPRequest:

```
function getDataByXHR(method, url) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.response);
    gameSettings = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    console.log(gameSettings);
    this.data = gameSettings;
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.error("An error occur getting the XMLHttpRequest");
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

How can I pass them into a function like this

```
function waitConsoleLog() {
  const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  };
  let count = 0;
  console.log(this.data);
  for (let index = 0; index < this.data.length; index++) {
    async (element) => {
      count++;
      await sleep(500 * count);
      console.log(element);
    };
  }
}
```

to use in the for loop since data/gameSettings always return as undefined

Comment: Try assigning the JSON to a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using:

```
function getDataByXHR(method, url) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.response);
    gameSettings = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    console.log(gameSettings);
    this.data = gameSettings;
    waitConsoleLog(this.data)
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.error("An error occur getting the XMLHttpRequest");
  };
  xhr.send();
}

function waitConsoleLog(data) {
  const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  };
  let count = 0;
  console.log(data);
  for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    async (element) => {
      count++;
      await sleep(500 * count);
      console.log(element);
    };
  }
}
```